# Convert List<Tuple> to List<Bean>

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I don't want to show all my attributes on a table, so I'd like to select only a few columns and then map their values to a bean, something similar to Hibernate's `Transformers.aliasToBean(T.class)`, but using JPA and Criteria.

I'm able to get a `List<Tuple>`, how could I transform it into a `List<T>`?

As the the title says, is it possible?

Comment: If you don't have a problem with _not_ using JPA or Criteria, then you could try [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I've seen Dozer, but couldn't find a way to use it dynamically, since my querys are created on runtime.

I thought there might be some way to do it using streams/lambdas/reflection but not sure how hard/possible is that

Comment: Is that `List<T>` in an abstract class whose generic type param is `T`? If yes, you could get `Class<T>` by reflection and create new instances by reflection. If you also have `Class<T>` as an argument, then you can use it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Within JPQL/Criteria queries you can provide arguments to an objects constructor within the query so that the query returns those objects for you.  For example:
  "SELECT new package.BeanClass(e.attribute1, e.attribute2) from Entity e"

With native SQL queries, if you are using JPA 2.1, you can use ConstructorResult to build the same instances: 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#ConstructorResult_.28JPA_2.1.29

But if you are not able to use Jpa 2.1, you will need a provider specific solution such as http://onpersistence.blogspot.com/2010/07/eclipselink-jpa-native-constructor.html